# Trying to get shorter link laravel

Tags: laravel, blogs

This is my first question in this forum so please be patient to me ;)
I'm making a blog using Laravel and
I have a page with a view of all articles inside my database
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HInWP.png)

Last column is "Action" column whet after hit the button you can see single article.
The problem is to show each content (title,subtitle etc.) i must create loooong UrL like this
http://127.0.0.1:8000/article/Test/Test/test/2020-05-08%2016:00:00

Is there any chance to cut URL to be like that:
http://127.0.0.1:800/article/Test
and still have all content?

**Files**

*web.php* 
Route::get('article/{title_article}/{subtitle_created}/{text_article}/{created_at}','ReadController@index');

*Controller*

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Article;
class ReadController extends Controller
{
        public function index($title_article,$subtitle_article,$text_article,$created_at) 
        {
            return view('article',compact('title_article','subtitle_article','text_article','created_at'))->with('title','Artykuł');
        }
}
```

Comment: Where the article come from? It doesn't have an ID? The way you are doing is very weird. Anything someone type will be valid. The article text could not be long due to url size limitations...

Comment: each article has an ID but I don't write it down on code

Comment: But you should. On each button you should link to `.../article/{the article id here}`. So on your controller you use it to load the model and get it columns to show. That's how it supposed to work. You should really read Laravel docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `primary key` (probably an incrementing id) of your database object (App\Article) to identify the object. Laravel has a wonderful function to automatically convert the `primary key (id)` in the route to an `eloquent model`.

In your case:

`Route::get('article/{article}','ReadController@index');`

and

`public function index(Article $article) { ... }`

I hope this helps you. If you don't understand parts of it, feel free to ask :)

Comment: Ok i'm getting closer  BUT now I have something like that : {"id":3,"title_article":"Test","subtitle_article":"Test","text_article":"test","created_at":"2020-05-08T16:00:00.000000Z","updated_at":null}... how to fix it?

Comment: Can you please add your current code into your post? You can just access all parameters with `$article->text_article` for example.

Comment: now everything is correct, thank you sooooooo much !!

Comment: No problem :) Please mark/vote my answer if it helped you.